# UPS address check failure

Tags: expresso-store, ups-shipping

Is there a technique with Expresso store that allows for a recourse if a user's shipping address fails the UPS address checker?

As it stands now if an address fails the UPS test, there is no shipping offered because UPS cannot locate the user's address, and so the user checks out without having a shipping method chosen and a potentially undeliverable address.

Has anyone built a recourse like this, and if so, what does it involve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting a default Country/State in Store > Settings > Countries/States? Also, do you have any other shipping methods or is UPS the only one?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Ian. Currently this is the only shipping method outside of a certain very close geographical area. The product is sensitive to temperature so quick delivery is of the essence. We do have a default Country - but the client doesn't want to enable a default State, as they're trying to appear less local and the logical default would bypass UPS entirely. I suppose a tiny shipping charge is better than no shipping charge.

Comment: Does UPS also offer an address validation/correction API? If so, perhaps you could use that to validate and correct the addresses before they get submitted into the cart for calculating rates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPS has multiple APIs that can be used.

You would need to write an extension that uses the Address Validation - Street Level API ([API Details](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US)) to pass the users shipping details to first check to see if the address is valid or not. If the address is not valid the API should return a list of possible address that might be correct (if I remember correctly) or allow the user to enter the address differently.

Once you have a valid address you will need to use the Rating API ([Rating API Details](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US)) to request the actual shipping rates and options that the user can select. I don't have access to the Store UPS shipping module at the moment but I believe this is the API that is used to calculate rates.